# Custom namespace not recognised in VS2008 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-3.5

I have moved what was a C# ASP Web Site over to be a C# ASP Web Application. I did this so I can do things like add Pre-Build events.

Everything seems to be nearly working correctly except some namespaces which I have declared in .cs files in my App_Code folder are not being recognised.

I get build errors such as

`The type or namespace name 'nsAppGlobal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I have a .cs file which quite clearly declares this namespace. For some reason Intellisense and the compiler both can't see it.

I have heard that I can solve this problem by building my namespace into a dll library and then including *that* in the web-application. This sounds pretty silly - because how then would I edit that code? I would have to edit in another project and rebuild the dll?

Has anyone encountered this problem? What is the best strategy for using namespaces in web application projects?

Comment: do you have multiple projects involved? are you including your files in your project?

Comment: No this is all in one project. I have pulled in a couple of .cs files from other project which declare their own namespaces. This wasn't a problem when the project was a WebSite as opposed to a Web Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this behavior, too, when [migrating a web site to a web application](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/differences-between-web-site-project-and-web-application-project/): it seems the App_Code directory is ignored due to its "magical" name.

The solution was easy: simply rename the App_Code directory.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of solution I'm looking for! I will try this in the morning. One question - I rename App_code from what to what?!

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to have worked. It wouldn't let me rename so I made a new folder called `Code` and put all the `.cs` files in there. Same error. Also I've noticed that `System.Data` isn't being recognised... Oh dear :(

Comment: **UPDATE** My actual issue was I think related to not having the .designer.cs files - as well as having an App_Code folder. I think if I'd have done it the correct way rather than just copying the files into the web-app I would not have had this problem. The way I ended up doing it was creating a blank web-app and adding new Webforms to that and then pasting my code in. I only have 3 pages so it wasn't much of an issue...

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when converting a website to a web application the Global.asax namespace gets corrupted. The Global.asax.cs will have the correct namespace, but the Global.asax will not.

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WILD.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

By default when you open the Global.asax, it opens the associated C# file. You want to view the markup. Make sure the attribute "**Inherits**" matches the Global.asax.cs namespace.

Comment: Hi, I'm not at my machine at present but this sounds hopeful so you're getting a +1. I didn't use an actual conversion tool or anything to convert it, I basically dragged the entire web page project files into the web application. Probably a stupid way to do it but I don't really understand the diff between sites and apps yet. Pretty sure I'm gonna learn before long!